# Why am I getting derivative of $y = 1/x$ function as $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was finding the derivative of the function: $y = 1/x$. I did the followed steps:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{1}{x+dx} - \frac{1}{x}}{dx} &=\left(\frac{1}{x+dx} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \frac{1}{dx} \\
&= \frac{1}{x dx + (dx)^2} - \frac{1}{x dx}.
\end{align*}

Since, $(dx)^2$ would be extremely small, I removed it, so

$$\frac{1}{x dx} - \frac{1}{x dx}$$

which is equal to zero.

why am I getting the derivative of $y = 1/x$ as $0$?

Comment: Your working is extremely ambiguous and unclear. Please use MathJax to format your work; here is a  reference page for it -- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Taking common denominator in $\frac{1}{xdx +(dx)^2} - \frac 1{xdx}$ gives $\frac{-(dx)^2}{x^2(dx)^2 + x(dx)^3} = \frac{-1}{x^2 + dx}$, where you can take $dx = 0$. Basically, the mistake is simple : even if $(dx)^2$ is small, it is not small enough to affect where that expression is going when $dx$ goes to $0$, so removing it is incorrect. Besides, $\frac{1}{xdx} - \frac 1{xdx}$ is an infinity minus infinity situation.

Comment: Additionally, (please reply!) who encourages you to make these $dx$ manipulations when there is a limit method to find the derivative? Something you learn in school?

Comment: @астон вілла тереса лисбон It's the definition of derivative : $\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + dx) - f(x)}{dx}$

Comment: You should avoid using $dx$, instead use $h$, which is the standard notation.

Comment: Ok, thank you everyone, I was using dx because when i learnt taking derivative, i was taught by using dx, so i was using dx.

Comment: @DavidLui But eliminating $(dx)^2 $ as $0$ : i mean he has been misguided somewhere. If the true limit was being kept in mind through the computation, then such an error won't be made.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон that is not an infinity - infinity situation because dx is very close to 0, but not 0

Comment: @DhruvAgarwal Right, sorry about that. My first point in that comment still stands. "When I learnt derivative, I was taught by using $dx$" then you have to be careful of this kind of mistake in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Do not remove $(dx)^2$:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x+dx} - \frac{1}{x}}{dx}=\frac{x-(x+dx)}{(x+dx)xdx}=-\frac{1}{x(x+dx)} \to -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Why it doesn't work can be seen by quantifying how accurate the approximation $f(x+y) \approx f(x)$ is. This is rightfully a zeroth order Taylor expansion,
$$ f(x+dx) = f(x) + O(dx) $$
for the function $f(x)=1/x$, we see
$$ \frac1{x+dx}-\frac1x = O(dx)$$
and therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac{1}{x+dx} - \frac{1}{x}}{dx} &=\left(\frac{1}{x+dx} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \frac{1}{dx} \\
&= O(dx)\frac1{dx} \\&= O(1).
\end{align*}
$O(1)$ quantities are not zero as $dx\to0$, so we cannot conclude as you did. Instead, we need to use a more accurate expansion like a first order Taylor expansion (but that's a little circular), or be more careful in your algebraic manipulations like the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\,d}{\,dx} \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-(x+h)}{hx(x+h)}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} -\frac{1}{x(x+h)}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The view of standard analysis has been clarified well.

Here is a explanation in the view of non-standard analysis.
If $a\approx b$, is $\frac{1}{a}\approx \frac{1}{b}$?
$a\approx b$ means that $|a-b|$ is small enough. After multiplying $|\frac{1}{ab}|$, we get $|\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}|$. But one cannot assure that this is also sufficiently small, this is because $|\frac{1}{ab}|$ can be infinitely large.

To be precise, small enough means smaller than any $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and large enough means that larger than any positive integers.
The only small enough (or, say infinitesimal) element in the real number is nothing but $0$, but there are more in the hyperreal number.